# How to build a developer-only UI section in React?

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I am building a website in React that lets users upload images. For a normal user, I'd want to display just the upload interface. But if accessed from the company's internal network, I'd want to show extra features such as the ability to delete any photo on the system.

What is the recommended way of doing so? The default approach I would take is to call a backend controller such as /isDeveloper and then show a separate UI section based on the response, but I'm not sure how well that fits into React's "philosophy". Another approach is to completely obfuscate the internal UI by fetching the "admin panel" code section from the server if the user is authorized to do so.

Comment: When working with React, you're going to want some form of state management, such as Redux, to handle user sessions, interactions, and so forth. Depending on how your authentication works, you could return a role variable for each user and display the appropriate fields given the role(s) the user currently has.

See: https://hackernoon.com/role-based-authorization-in-react-c70bb7641db4

Comment: @Haus I do use Redux to manage the state and I could indeed have a "isDeveloper" boolean in the state, but wanted to double check that this is the recommended approach

Answer (score 1):

you basically want to have a `admin` and `user` account.

So in this case best would be, when the application loads for the first time, user logs in and you get details of the user and in the response from backend, which will have information whether user is a normal user or an admin.

Based on that you can use state in react to show and hide different components.
You can also create a Higher order component in react which will check if user is normal user or an admin and accordingly will show/hide the component.

You can also use redux for state management of the app. There are plenty of options. It always depends upon how big your application is.

Comment: For additional security, you'll probably want to double check requests in the backend to verify that nobody has been playing with the client-side javascript (i.e. displaying admin forms as a non-admin)